# Half page background / Column background

Tags: javascript, html, css, multiple-columns

I'm running this JavaScript and CSS ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6ao2vk2/1/)) on this website ([animevid-other](http://animevid-other.webflow.com/)) so what I need is to adapt the JavaScript and CSS to the `column_sx` or have the background centered on the left (where there's the column), is this possible?

I've found something that could have helped but I think it's not exactly what I need ([multiple-backgrounds-left-half-and-right-half](http://css-tricks.com/multiple-backgrounds-left-half-and-right-half/)). So since I have not so much knowledge of JavaScript and just a few things about CSS, could you help me?

Edit : more details here https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4fSm.png

Comment: Your jsfiddle demo is full of empty :) You didn't save the fiddle.

Comment: pardon, should be fixed :D

Comment: Could you explain more what you want exactly, I didn't understand. You want the background in left column to be center of that column?

Comment: sure, so what I need is or apply the script to the column background, or center the page background relative to the column sx (see here : http://i.imgur.com/DsF4q3M.png ) hope you understood :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the background to colonna_sx instead of body. So add this to colonna_sx.

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
```

Then you should change the script. If you add jQuery you can change this.

```
 document.body.background ='http://adventureofucm.com/OtherSites/image_background/'+num+'.jpg';
```

to this.

```
var backgroundpic = 'http://adventureofucm.com/OtherSites/image_background/'+num+'.jpg';
$('.colonna_sx').css("background", "url(backgroundpic)");
```

Without jQuery.

```
document.querySelector('div.colonna_sx').style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://adventureofucm.com/OtherSites/image_background/' + num + '.jpg)';
```

This should work in most browsers (IE8 and up) http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what i need, cause the bg is chosen by a script

Comment: I edited my answer. You should change the script so it adds the backgound to colonna_sx instead of your body.

Comment: ok, i think i'll use this if nothing better is found, no way to do this without jquery ?

Comment: I added the script for normal javascript. This should work in most browsers.

Comment: ok, so your answer is definitely the best :D
it's just... I think I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Maybe I can help you further if you contact me. You can go to my site for my contact details.

Comment: could be cause colonna_sx is inside 2_column ?